# Vimeo api play IE8

Tags: javascript, api, internet-explorer-8, vimeo

When trying to add an autoplay through vimeo API I get the following error on IE8 and lower:

Object doesn't support this property or method. Line 24, Char 449 from moogaloop.js

This is the script I use.

```
var player = '';

function vimeoready(player_id) {

    player = $f(player_id);

    player.api('play');
}

$f(document.getElementById('vimeo-video')).addEvent('ready', vimeoready);
```

Is there anything that causes this?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and 9 don't seem to work well with the api. However, you can autoplay a vimeo video by adding ?autoplay=1 on the video source URL.